# Template argument deduction/substitution failed when using linearRegression in Eigen 2 library

Tags: c++, eigen

I am working in an existing C++ codebase and am having trouble calling a function.

I am trying to use the linear regression function from an older Eigen library already in the codebase, you can see [that source code here](https://github.com/IGNF/ContinuousGeneralisation/blob/master/ContinuousGeneralizer/Citations/eigen/Eigen/src/Eigen2Support/LeastSquares.h) but below is the relevant declaration.

```
template<typename VectorType>
void linearRegression(int numPoints,
                      VectorType **points,
                      VectorType *result,
                      int funcOfOthers )
{ ... }
```

Below is an anonymized copy of my code:

```
// MyClass has member variable int maxIdx = 5
void MyClass::myFunction()
{
    Eigen::Vector2d points[maxIdx];
    Eigen::Vector2d coeffs;
    for(int i = 0; i < maxIdx; i++)
    {
        points[i] = Eigen::Vector2d(data->mydata[i].x, data->mydata[i].y);
    }
    Eigen::linearRegression( maxIdx, &points, &coeffs, 1 );

    // do more stuff with coeffs
}
```

And this is the error message I get when I try to compile:

```
myfile.cpp:803:67: error: no matching function for call to 'linearRegression(int, Eigen::Vector2d (*)[((MyClass*)this)->MyClass::maxIdx], Eigen::Vector2d*, int)'
         Eigen::linearRegression( maxIdx, &points, &coeffs, 1 );
                                                                   ^
myfile.cpp:803:67: note: candidate is:
In file included from [redacted]:
lib/Eigen/src/Eigen2Support/LeastSquares.h:85:6: note: template<class VectorType> void Eigen::linearRegression(int, VectorType**, VectorType*, int)
 void linearRegression(int numPoints,
      ^
lib/Eigen/src/Eigen2Support/LeastSquares.h:85:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
myfile.cpp:803:67: note:   mismatched types 'VectorType*' and 'Eigen::Vector2d [((MyClass*)this)->MyClass::maxIdx] {aka Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> [((MyClass*)this)->MyClass::maxIdx]}'
```

This is pretty much an exact copy of the example code in the library's source, so I'm a bit at a loss of how to fix this. I'm not super familiar with templates, so the type error may be related to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to *that* source (and unlike what’s written in their example), `points` is expected to be an array of pointers to the points. That is,

`Eigen::Vector2d *points[maxIdx];`

So,

```
Eigen::Vector2d points[maxIdx];
Eigen::Vector2d *point_ptrs[maxIdx];
for(int i = 0; i < maxIdx; i++)
    point_ptrs[i] = &points[i];
...
Eigen::linearRegression(maxIdx, point_ptrs, &coeffs, 1);
```

That seems stupid for `Vector2d` but is probably designed for huge vectors which aren’t nice to copy.

Answer (score 0):

To tack on to @numzero's answer, that code compiled but I was getting a runtime crash when I tried to execute it. It looks like second argument needs to be to the *first index* in that array of pointers. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810270/assigning-elements-to-eigenvector2d-within-std-vector-throws-error/49813969) explains what was happening and while it failed at runtime even though it compiled.

Here's what eventually worked for me:

```
Eigen::Vector2d points[numPoints];
Eigen::Vector2d* point_ptrs[numPoints];
Eigen::Vector2d coeffs;
for(int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
{
    points[i] = Eigen::Vector2d(data->mydata[i].x, data->mydata[i].y);
    point_ptrs[i] = &points[i];
}
Eigen::linearRegression( maxIdx, &(point_ptrs[0]), &coeffs, 1 );
```